# How to expand container height to max?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue trying to make one of my containers stretch to max screen height,

```
  home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I thought by making the height value infinity it would stretch the red container across the entirety of the safe area.
Although the container is invisible unless I put a value in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `Expanded` widget.

> According to the official documentation, An `Expanded` widget is a widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

Read more about the `Expanded` widget here: [Expanded Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*OUTPUT*
[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! have just implemented this into some of my code and it works. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the container to Expanded will make its size max like this :

```
home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
        Expanded(
         child: Container(
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
         )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```